# WHERE clause on VARCHAR column seems to operate as a LIKE

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-like, varchar

I've stumbled across a situation I've never seen before. I hope that someone can explain the following.

I've ran the following query, hoping to get only the results of columns whoes value is exactly equal to `1101`

```
select '--' + MyColumn + '--' SeeSpaces, Len(MyColumn) as LengthOfColumn 
from MyTable 
where MyColumn = '1101'
```

However, I also see values where `1101` is followed by (what I believe are) spaces.

So `SeeSpaces` returns

```
--1101&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--
```

And `LengthOfColumn` returns `4`

`MyColumn` is a `VARCHAR(8), NOT NULL` column. Its values (including the spaces) are inserted through a separate workflow.

Why does this select not return only the exact results?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is to do with the way that SQL server compares strings with trailing spaces, it follows the ANSI standard and so the strings '1101' and '1101 ' are equivalent.

See the following for more details:

[INF: How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626)

Comment: Thank you... this explained it to me. And also thank you for answering in an adult way in stead of the first poster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `LTRIM() and RTRIM()` function while comparing like :

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(MYCOLUMN))='1101'
```

Also `LEN` function does not count spaces, it only count characters in string. Please refere :   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329%28SQL.90%29.aspx